# Database query proxy over http or webservice

Tags: database, web-services, entity-framework, proxy

I've seen various schemes for querying databases over http and webservice interfaces etc. Curious if there is some kind of standard for this, and a way to expose it as a normal database connection on the client side.

For instance: something that would let me define a db connection, which could then be used with an entity framework connection inside the client code. I could then issue queries against it in such a way that it looks just like a normal database connection.

Comment: See [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx)

Comment: John, would this allow me to transparently use entity framework to query a sql database on an http server? I see a bunch of OData discussion but doesnt seem exactly what I'm looking for, unless Im missing something

Comment: Yes, this would permit that. OData is simply the high-level protocol being used. You would build an EF model of those parts of your data that you wish to expose, organized the way you want to expose it. You would not need to stick to the current structure of the database - you could expose your data in a manner that makes more sense to the consumers of the data.

Comment: could i use this in such a way that I could unplug from a local database and plug this in, and the software not know the difference?

Comment: I've never actually used this technology. In an ideal world, I suppose the "Add Service Reference" proxy code might look exactly like the "local" entity framework code. Otherwise, you'll need to write and use adapters.

Comment: ok, so looks like this doesnt exist in the wild. thanks for the input john.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions. The fact that _I_ haven't used it doesn't mean it's not successfully used every day!

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is not doing what I'm asking about though. 
But, you do give me a genius idea...a jump... to conclusions.. matt!